# AndroidStudio webview doesn't load untrusted certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, web, webview

I have a webpage that I show with a webview in Android Studio.
To see the web page I use a https request with a self-signed certificate. Unfortunately Android Studio doesn't recognize the certificate and return a white page. What can I do?

Comment: are you sure your code is implemented perfectly?? if not, without your code how can we find the problem??

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the code, the only problem is about the untrusted certificate